# Learning Mathematics in a Difficult Situation

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, learning

I'm in high school right now and I feel so lost in math. It's not so much about doing the problems but it's more so establishing a firm base of understanding that I need. I feel as if I need to learn all the math I have learned from all over again. Should I? If I do, how fast would I be able to learn everything to be prepared for next year? If not, then where should I start from?

I apologize for asking such questions when you guys don't have much info. I'm in my advanced math class and I've gotten A-'s for the last two semesters. Maybe I'm overthinking it but I feel as if I need to establish a new base again.

The issues I have had with understanding stem from such basic concepts too, like why can I do the distributive property or why can I split the square root of 36 into the square root of 4 and the square root of 9. I feel as if I really lack in abstract thinking.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\sqrt{12}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{\color{red}3}$

Comment: Thank you, sorry I meant to say the square root of 36

Comment: If you are allowed to study mathematics in the bathtub only, something really is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by bathtub?

Comment: @ManMan all of these issues you mentioned will be resolved when you're introduced to proofs, groups, rings and fields. At your level, you usually rely on  informal arguments. That is precisely why you feel that way. Advanced math, usually formalizes all of the informal arguments and the hand waviness.

Comment: Aren't I already introduced to proofs? What do you mean by informal arguments too? Are you saying that as I go on I will get a more solid grasp of math? Also, when would I learn these rings and fields?

Comment: It depends on the teacher you have. In my case I was told for example that a continuous function is a function, whose graph you can draw without lifting your pencil. There were many such intuitive arguments and while they motivate proper definitions and proofs they still are dangerous in the sense that they might fail with an counterintuitive counterexample. E.g. in analysis there is a 3d shape, which you can fill with finitely many paint, but not paint the outside (ie. finite volume, Infinitiv surface area). Modern mathematics is about translating intuitive ideas into a more rigorous form.

Comment: An intuitive definition of ring (field) would be a general number system where you can add and multiply elements like in $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q, \mathbb R$. The distinction between ring and field is that in a field every nonzero element $a$ has to have a multiplicative inverse element $b$ such that $ab=1=ba$. So $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ are fields, while $\mathbb Z$ is „just“ a ring. Again this is an informal introduction to rings and fields as it relies on your intuitive understanding of the examples. For a mathematically precise definition of ring/field consider the ones given on wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest volunteering to tutor younger students.  (Could be anything from elementary to freshmen)  Much of what you are talking about in terms of "basic concepts" will come to you more fully when you are explaining it to someone else.  Teaching a concept often forces you to look at problems and concepts in different ways than you normally would. 
It helps deepen your understanding and forces you to consider the basics more carefully.

Consider how an elementary student first learns to multiply.  You may even remember doing the repeated addition before you memorized your multiplication tables. (not sure they still call them that ;-)) --That's the key to your distributive property puzzle by the way.--

$a\cdot b$ means add $a$, $b$ times.
$a\cdot c$ means add $a$, $c$ times.
$a\cdot b +a\cdot c$ means add $a$, $b$ times then add $a$, $c$ more times.  Hence, adding $a$ a total of $(b+c)$ times.  So, $ab+ac=a(b+c).

As a High School student, tutoring would also provide you with community service and leadership for clubs and honor societies (not to mention college applications).